# Compare two hashed Strings and distribute to elements in Java

Tags: java, string, hash, comparison

I'm hashing with SHA-1 some Strings (IDs) and i'm comparing them with other hashed (also with SHA-1) Strings (which are referred to elements), and i want to distribute the IDs to the elements. I want to distribute them with the statement (hashedId < hashedStringElement1, 2 or 3). For test purposes as you can see below i put counters and an error print if the hashedID cant go to an Element. Every hashedID must go to Element1, 2 or 3. For correct distribution i think i could use the MOD function but i don't know how. It's ok if the IDs are not distributed equally but they have to go somewhere.

SHA-1 method

```
public static String simpleHashFunc(String a) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(a.getBytes());
            BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);

            String hashtext = no.toString(16);

            while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
                hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
            }

            return hashtext;

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Testing Lines

```
 int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0, counter4 =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < topics.size(); i++) {
            String tempHash = Broker.simpleHashFunc(topics.get(i).getBusLine().getBuslineId());
            if (tempHash.compareTo(hashedBrokers.get(0)) == -1) {
                counter1++;
                //Distribution to element1
            } else if (tempHash.compareTo(hashedBrokers.get(1)) == -1) {
                counter2++;
                //Distribution to element2
            } else if (tempHash.compareTo(hashedBrokers.get(2)) == -1) {
                counter3++;
                //Distribution to element3
            } else {
                System.out.println("Cant go to broker: " + topics.get(i).getBusLine().getBuslineId());
                counter4++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter1 + "  " + counter2 + "  " + counter3 + "  " + counter4);
//The majority of IDs go to to else { } and the counter4 has the greatest number.
```

Expected results:

Out of 37IDs: 20 to element1, 10 to element2, 7 to element3

Expected results:

Out of 37IDs: 25 to element1, 10 to element2, 2 to element3
....

Actual results:

Out of 37IDs: 5 to element1, 10 to element2, 2 to element3, 20 ids cant go to element

Comment: Why have you decided on this sort of distribution function? SHA1 string comparison makes no real-world sense.

Comment: You may want to look at the implementation of e.g. `HashMap`, how it hashes its elements and how it distribute them across the buckets.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it's in the instructions for a project and it's necessary.  :/

Comment: Well, then, I don't understand how you thought to incorporate the mod function. Suppose for a moment that it's not SHA1 hashes but simple numbers. You have 1, 50 and 100. And you want to distribute them with that requirement. Clearly, any number above 100 is going to fail. What would you use mod for? How would you do that in a way that would not break the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can go to else statement and then do it from the begining with the mod function ids % elements.size(). Mod can be 0,1,2. We use the BigInteger class for accuracy

```
//hashing buslineIDs and distributing to correct Brokers
            int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0, counter4 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < topics.size(); i++) {
                String tempHash = Broker.simpleHashFunc(topics.get(i).getBusLine().getBuslineId());
                if (tempHash.compareTo(hashedBrokers.get(0)) == -1) {
                    counter1++;
                    //add responsibility line
                } else if (tempHash.compareTo(hashedBrokers.get(1)) == -1) {
                    counter2++;
                } else if (tempHash.compareTo(hashedBrokers.get(2)) == -1) {
                    counter3++;
                } else {
                    counter4++;
                    BigInteger tempHashBig = new BigInteger(tempHash, 32);
                    //System.out.println(tempHashBig);
                    if (tempHashBig.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(hashedBrokers.size())).equals(BigInteger.valueOf(0))) {
                        counter1++;
                    } else if (tempHashBig.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(hashedBrokers.size())).equals(BigInteger.valueOf(1))) {
                        counter2++;
                    } else if (tempHashBig.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(hashedBrokers.size())).equals(BigInteger.valueOf(2))) {
                        counter3++;
                    }

                }


            }
```